# hosting express server with nginx

Tags: nginx

I want to host my express website with nginx on aws. So I followed this [tutorial](https://medium.com/today-i-learned-chai/setup-node-js-application-with-pm2-and-nginx-72840f44ea73), but replacing the express app with my own app, and after changing the port to the same as my express app, I fired up my node app, it said the port has been used `Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8000`.

My Express app is at `/usr/share/nginx/html/mysite`

Am I misunderstanding something?

My `nginx.conf`:

`server {
  listen 80;
  server_name my_public_ip;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }
}`

If this isn't the right place to ask, sorry, please let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're already running some program that listens on port 8000. You have to stop it first, before you can start another one.

Comment: So I changed the port, it worked, but why is it serving the nginx welcome page instead of my website when I go onto my private ip. Could you please explain it to me, cause I don't want to just follow some tutorial and bang it worked. Thank you in advanced.